# How to remove dependency analysis error in Sinch?

Tags: ios, sinch

Please give me solution for Sinch Message Chat

```
Unable to run command 'Ld SinchService' - this target might include its own product.
Unable to run command 'Touch SinchService.framework' - this target might include its own product.
Unable to run command 'CodeSign SinchService.framework' - this target might include its own product.
```

Comment: @rmaddy do you have any solution for this?

Comment: @Murloc It's Sinch Message chat issue. please have a look here: https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/ios-instant-messaging-using-sinchservice/

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using ? Did you run pod install ?

Comment: @Murloc i want to run **Sinch instant message chat** in _swift_  project by using _bridgeheader_ I use **pods** _SinchService_ and _Sinch ‘RTC’_

Comment: without **pod** install its shows this error in project Undefined symbols for _architecture i386_
   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Sinch", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SINOutgoingMessage", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MainViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Xcode version is 8.2.

Answer (score 1):

Select the target in your Xcode project and click the Build Phases tab.

Look at the Target Dependencies list, the target's product should not be listed there, but apparently it sounds like it may have been added to that list by mistake.

Also check the other tabs -- you don't want your product listed in Copy Bundle Resources or Link Binary With Libraries, either.

You obviously can't use what you're building as a resource or library to build the product in the first place.

That's what Xcode seems to be complaining about.